# Limiting total Core file sizes to 10% of disk usage in ArchLinux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, core-dump

I need to limit the total core files sizes generated to be 10% of my disk usage. I have set `ulimit -c` to be unlimited stating that each file size is unlimited. Then I used the configuration file
`/etc/systemd/coredump.conf.d/custom.conf` to set

```
[Coredump]
Storage=external
#Compress=yes
#ProcessSizeMax=2G
#ExternalSizeMax=2G
#JournalSizeMax=767M
MaxUse=10
#KeepFree=15
```

I thought this configuration file will limit the disk usage to 10%. But still the core file usage exceeds 10%.

I tried setting the `Storage=none`, but still I got the core files generated. Setting the `ulimit -c` to 0 stopped generating core files. But I want the disk usage to be 10%. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: Does `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` contain `|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %p %u %g %s %t %e`, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

**MaxUse=10** actually says to clean all the older dumps if the total size of dumps exceeds 10bytes.

As per the source code which is mentioned in the link below:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/4e4e3d97664163267d8295e6f58e0ff8560bea33/src/basic/parse-util.c#L109

It looks like the MaxUse is an argument which takes **Size** and **NOT** percentage, looks like the man page is little misleading here.

The MaxUse takes only size and it should be either of the suffixes mentioned in this set -> {**"E","P","T","G","M","K","B",""**} .

Any number without the suffix will be by default considered as Bytes.